# if/else statement not executing 'if' statement

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to print some complex numbers. If the complex number (modTrace) is like 'a-ib' then my code:

```
modTrace
v = [real(modTrace(:)) imag(modTrace(:))].';
fprintf(fileID,'%e+%ei\n',v);
```

gives the output as:

```
2.355387e-13+-7.217925e-13i
```

To avoid the extra + sign in front of the negative imaginary piece I write:

```
v = [real(modTrace(:)) imag(modTrace(:))].';
if imag(modTrace(:))>0
    fprintf(fileID,'%e+%ei\n',v);
else
    fprintf(fileID,'%e%ei\n',v);
end
```

Now in the output the 'if' is not being executed. So if I have a complex number 'a+ib' it prints 
'a bi' and if a complex number is 'a-ib' it prints 'a-bi' according to the else statement.

if I then modify the code like:

```
v = [real(modTrace(:)) imag(modTrace(:))].';
if imag(modTrace(:))<0
    fprintf(fileID,'%e%ei\n',v);
else
    fprintf(fileID,'%e+%ei\n',v);
end
```

then again the 'if' statement in not being executed. So for a complex number 'a-ib' the output is 'a+-bi' and the 'else' statement in being executed correctly.

Could any body please help me to find the output in the correct form? 
Thanks.

Comment: is `modTrace` a vector of many complex numbers? If so then `if imag(modTrace(:))>0` will only check the condition on the first element. conditions expect scalars.

Comment: Yes, modTrace is a vector of many complex numbers. I am not sure how the code is executing the 'else' statement correctly but not the 'if' statement. I have been using matlab for 1 week, so I think I am missing something.

Comment: It executing them both correctly, but it only chooses once. So if you first element has a negative imaginary number, then it will go with the `if` clause, but if it had a positive imaginary number then it will go with the `else` clause for all your elements because you are only choosing once. You need to write a loop like in my answer

Comment: There's no condition on the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this case you are better off using a loop:

```
for k = 1:length(modTrace)
    if imag(modTrace(k))>0
        fprintf(fileID,'%e+%ei\n',real(modTrace(k)), imag(modTrace(k)));
    else
        fprintf(fileID,'%e%ei\n',real(modTrace(k)), imag(modTrace(k)));
    end
end
```

You can't vectorize it that easily because if you pass a vector to `if` it only evaluates true when (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html):

> the result is nonempty and contains all nonzero elements (logical or
>   real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false.

Comment: I don't think that it's true it evaluates only the first element, in my experience (unless this has changed over time).  e.g. `if 1:10<2` will fail even though the condition is true for the first element.

Comment: @nkjt thanks, you're right. I checked the docs and have corrected my answer.

Comment: The code using loop works. Thanks. It is also printing the complex numbers correctly. I was wondering because 'modTrace' is a vector so without transposing it if it would produce correct result. But it is producing correct result! I compared it with the output using transposing the vector. It is producing the same complex number and it gets rid of the extra + sign in front of the negative imaginary pieces. You guys are great!

Comment: @user3389597 Just make sure you understand the take home message here which is do not feed vectors to an `if` statement in Matlab!

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes, I have been reading and trying to understand it more.